# examples where some point of the Gromov-Hausdorff limit space has non-unique tangent cones

Tags: geometry

Suppose $\left( {{M_i},{q_i}} \right)\mathop  \to \limits^{G - H} \left( {X,{q_\infty }} \right)$, ${\rm Ric}_{M_i} \ge  - \left( {n - 1} \right)$, and ${q_\infty }$ is regular, i.e. all the tangent cones are equal to ${R^k}$ where $k$ depends on $p$.

Then can we find a sequence ${\lambda _i} \to \infty $,such that $\left( {{\lambda _i}{M_i},{q_i}} \right)\mathop  \to \limits^{G - H} \left( {{R^k},0} \right)$? And is there an example where some point of the limit place has non-unique tangent cones?

Comment: [Cross-posted](http://mathoverflow.net/q/135088) (and answered) at MO.